# In a Group, prove that there is a $g=k^2$ where $k∈G$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups

Given $(G, ∗, I)$ a group where $g ∈ G$, it satisfies $g^n=I$ for some odd number $n$.

How can I prove that there is a $g=k^2$ where $k∈G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$. You have then $g^{2k+1} = I$.

Multiply this equality by $g$, and you get

$$g^{2k+1}g = g$$

Hence

$$g^{2(k+1)} = g$$

But $g^{2(k+1)} = g^{k+1} g^{k+1} = (g^{k+1})^2$

So finally we have

$$g = h^2 \text{ where } h =g^{k+1}$$